# AWS Cognito user pre-sign up validation. To check if user exist in other DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm currently migrating my DB based user directory to AWS Cognito. I'm using `migration` trigger for migrating existing users. This working fine.

My issue, What if an existing email id is used for `SignUp`. So I thought to add `PreSignUp` trigger which checks user exists in DB and also make auto confirmation for all users.

My question is **how can I make a response from trigger when a User exists ? 
What kinda JSON object the cognito is expecting, So that in client side it gives `UserExistsException`.?**

Draft Code.

```
def handler(event, context):
    event['response']['autoConfirmUser'] = True

    if event['request']['userAttributes']['email'] is not None:
        if not user_exists(event['request']['userAttributes']['email']):
            event['response']['autoVerifyEmail'] = True
        else:
            return #Validation Error response

    return event
```

Comment: Returning an ```Error()``` function is the best I've found so far. But I'm not sure its right. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html

Comment: Oh sorry, your using python. Here's the equivalent page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Cognito it automatically detects and throws an exception when someone tries to register with an existing email address. Therefore you can trigger the exception throwing out from Cognito and do the handling. So that from my opinion it is better to first check the user is exists in your DB and throw a custom exception without proceeding in to Cognito.

Comment: So the question would how should be the exception looks like. ? I need the message on client should clear.

Comment: If I return a string I'm getting `InvalidLambdaResponseException` this error from Client. 

I will checks if Exceptions handled perfectly over there.

Comment: raising Exception makes to add error message, with prefix  "PreSignUp failed with error" . I would like to show translated message. 

Seems like not possible with current situation.

Comment: If the exact fault is in registering the user who has already registered(confirmed or unconfirmed in cognito) with the same email address then the possible exceptions would be from Cognito is "AliasExistsException / UsernameExistsException".